# 'to be nothing to ...' vs 'to have nothing to ...'

Tags: difference

> [[60% down the page]](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ethics/euthanasia/against/against_1.shtml) Dying is not the same as never having been born
>   The debate **is** nothing to do with preventing disabled babies being born, or preventing people with disabilities from becoming parents

What are the similarities and differences between 'to be nothing to ...' vs 'to have nothing to ...' ?

Comment: Google Ngram says the form with *has* is way more prevalent in literature: 
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+nothing+to+do+with%2C+is+nothing+to+do+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20nothing%20to%20do%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20nothing%20to%20do%20with%3B%2Cc0

Comment: the `is` in that sentence sounds extremely awkward to me as a native (American) English speaker.

Answer (score 2):

I have only heard *has nothing to do with*, never *is nothing to do with*, in AmE. Perhaps the *is* expression is primarily British (the article you cite is British).

However, [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+nothing+to+do+with%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cis+nothing+to+do+with%3Aeng_us_2012%2Chas+nothing+to+do+with%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cis+nothing+to+do+with%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20nothing%20to%20do%20with%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20nothing%20to%20do%20with%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20nothing%20to%20do%20with%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20nothing%20to%20do%20with%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) suggests that the *is* expression is rarely used even in BrE.

Comment: There you are wrong. I think you have not read the question. The question is: "What are the similarities and differences between "to be nothing to" vs "to have nothing to"?

Comment: @Khan: Did you look at the cited article or the quoted passage from it?  In spite of the question's phrasing, it seems to me that the expressions being compared are in fact "has nothing to do **with**" and "is nothing to do **with**".

Comment: Drew, I am sorry. I should have looked at it in the context.

Comment: @Khan: No problem.

Comment: Drew, but it's a matter of grammar.

Comment: Drew, it's a matter of grammar. If you look up the phrase "be nothing to do with" in the Cambridge and The Free Dictionary, you will find it, which is used in place of the phrase "have nothing to do with".

Comment: @Khan: Yes, I realize that "is nothing to do with" is used, at least in British English. That accords with it having a dictionary entry, especially in a British dictionary. But it is apparently used only rarely, at least according to the Ngram I cited. Personally, I do not recall ever hearing it. But if I read it (e.g., in a British source) I would not be shocked or even necessarily notice it. This said, I don't have any idea what you mean by "it's a matter of grammar", here.

Comment: Dear Drew, it's also correct to say be nothing to do with as mentioned in American Advanced, Cambridge and the Free dictionaries even it's rarely used. So I mean it's not grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @Khan: No one has suggested that it is ungrammatical to say *is nothing to do with*. If, by saying "*it's a matter of grammar*", you are suggesting that the question here is about whether this is ungrammatical, then no, that is not the question raised here, at all. The OP asks for the  similarities and differences between the *is* and the *has* expressions.

Answer (score 0):

A woman is speaking on the phone about taking precipitate action. Her husband overhears part of the conversation, and thinks she is talking about rain (precipitation).

--It's going to be sunny, he says.

What we have been speaking of *has nothing to do with* the weather, she replies.

"To have nothing to do with X" means to be entirely unrelated to X.

A child overhears her parents speaking in hushed tones. She thinks they're going to be sending her to bed early.

-- It's nothing to do with you, says mother. We're talking about your brother.

Same meaning as "it has nothing to do with you."

EDIT: My treating "It's" in *It's nothing to do with you* as a contraction for "it is" has been challenged by Drew.  I think in that locution the contraction stands for "it is", not "it has"; there is a variant that goes:

-- It's got nothing to do with you

where the contraction does mean "it has".

Comment: It has the same meaning because here *it's* is a contraction of *it has*. So you are essentially repeating yourself.

Comment: I (as a native speaker) have my doubts that "It's" in "It's nothing to do with you" is definitely a contraction for "it has". I suspect that there it is a contraction for "it is", and that "it" refers to "what we have been speaking about". How would you *usually* say (using contractions) 1) "She has two legs" and 2) "It has four legs" ?

Comment: Whether you are familiar with it is not really the question. *It's* is a contraction for both *it is* and *it has*. Few people (nowadays, if ever) would say *It's four legs* as a replacement for *It has four legs*. But that is beside the point. Many people say *It's got nothing to do with you*, just as many say *It has got nothing to do with you* (and *It has nothing to do with you*).

Comment: My question is how can *you* be certain that "it's" is a contraction here for "it has" when "it is" is a viable meaning?  This has nothing to do with my familiarity or unfamiliarity.

Comment: OK, fair enough. There is no way to know whether it is a contraction for *it is* or *it has*, here. Perhaps I thought you had written *It's got nothing...* instead of *It's nothing*. But given the rarity of the use of *It is nothing to do with* (see my answer), I (personally) would still think of the contraction in *It's nothing to do with* as standing for *it has*. But yes, who's to say? If you had in fact written *It's* ***got*** *nothing to do with* then I would definitely argue that the contraction there stands for *it has*.

Comment: When the phrase is also listed in the American Oxford Advanced, Cambridge, the Free Dictionaries as be nothing to do with, it's clear that it's means it is in the phrase. So we should not waste our energies arguing over it's.